# Mounting of drive from script

Tags: bash, script, mount

I have this code:

```
echo "Mount External Backup @ $externalBackupDrivePath"
for uuid in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*;
    do 
    if [[ "$uuid" =~ $externalBackupDriveID ]]; then 
        if [[ $(mount | grep "$(readlink -e "$uuid")") ]]; then 
        echo "External BackUp Drive is mounted"; echo; else sudo mount UUID=$externalBackupDriveID $externalBackupDrivePath
        echo "External BackUp Drive is mounted"; echo
        fi
    fi
done
```

It is meant to look for my external drive, and mount it for use as a backUp drive in a script.
It works if the drive is on, but gives worrying result if it's off.  Would like to clean it up so I get a better result or a warning that the drive cannot be located.

The result I'm getting is:

```
[sudo] password for me: 
mount: UUID=: can't find in /etc/fstab.
External BackUp Drive is mounted

External BackUp Drive is mounted

mount: UUID=: can't find in /etc/fstab.
External BackUp Drive is mounted

External BackUp Drive is mounted

External BackUp Drive is mounted

External BackUp Drive is mounted
```

That output is erroneous, drive is NOT mounted or even powered on.
Would like my script to pick up on the fact that the drive isn't connected.

I've tried a bunch of things to no avail......................

Comment: "_I've tried a bunch of things_" - what have you tried? We weren't with you so can't know what you have tried. If you tell us, then we can avoid suggesting things that you've already tried, which wastes your time and ours

Comment: What shell does this run under? (What's your `#!` line, and how do you invoke the script?)

Comment: First thing, looking at your output `mount: UUID=: can't find in /etc/fstab` it's trivially obvious that `$externalBackupDriveID` isn't set

Comment: Second, the code you've provided has a number of other [errors that should be corrected](https://shellcheck.net/) before proceeding. Please provide example working code